# How to handle autofill address save popup in selenium webdriver ( Java )

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WquJ.jpg)I am getting the Address save pop up while the Automation script is running, how to disable / handle it
I am using Selenium- java  version 4.11.0  in maven and chrome version is 116.

could any one please help

I tried in selenium Maven TestNG framework
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addUserProfilePreference("autofill.profile_enabled", false);

I get error in "addUserProfilePreference"  not sure what seleinum import  i need to download

Answer (score 0):

autofill.profile_enabled is an experimental option and you need to add it using .setExperimentalOption() method

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("autofill.profile_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```